# Need help on PhpUnit

Tags: phpunit

Can you please suggest how to capture the network traffic in phpunit using selenium.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, that is currently not possible without heavy customization.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow this:
I'm afraid you might have to modify your selenium extension

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/issues/61

http://code.google.com/p/selenium-profiler/source/browse/trunk/web_profiler.py